# Visibility of class in Java

Tags: java, visibility

How to define **low visibility** and **high visibility** in java..??
Which will be the low visibility private or public

Comment: You can't find the meaning of public private in google ..OK.

Comment: I think his dictionary is broken too ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low visibility = `private`. High visibility = `public`. And there are two more visibilities in-between. From higher to lower visibility:

```
public > protected > "default" > private
```

"Default" doesn't have a keyword associated, it's the visibility that applies when no visibility is explicitly declared. And here's the relevant link from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 2):

This basically boils down to what the English word "visible" means.  Visible means "you can see it", and "high visibility" means that you can *see more* than "low visibility".

From that, it is intuitively obvious that 'private' is less visible than 'public' ... even if you don't understand what `private` and `public` mean in Java.

If you then read the Java tutorial page on [access control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), you will see that the way that Java defines the access control rules, and the way it uses the term "visibility" are both consistent with the intuitive meaning of the corresponding English words.